# Android Camera2 bufferqueue has been abandoned while starting a new activity

Tags: android, android-camera2

I'm trying to implement a app using google camera2 api and I'm following the code exactly same as listed out in this article https://inducesmile.com/android/android-camera2-api-example-tutorial/

My activity has a button and on click I'm saving the image to my storage and then  I'm passing the uri over an intent to a new activity where I'm displaying the image.I'm starting the new activity from the onCreate() method of the Mainactivity

App is working fine but it is always throwing the below error while starting the new activity
'bufferqueue has been abandoned'

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: I had this issue, and solved it by reordering how the camera resources get closed and released, ensuring the preview is stopped before the camera is closed.